# Expected ';' before '.' token, but '.' token is not there

Tags: c++, boost, vxworks

I'm trying to build the Boost C++ library on VxWorks 6.9 and I'm getting the following error regarding line 63 of boost/circular_buffer/debug.hpp:

`Error: expected ';' before '.' token`

Here is the code for the `debug_iterator_base` class that the error is referencing:

```
class debug_iterator_base {
private:
    mutable const debug_iterator_registry* m_registry;
    mutable const debug_iterator_base* m_next;  // this is line 63
    ...
```

The obvious problem is: **there is no period on that line**. If one of the relevant symbols were a macro then I'd have something to go on, but that is not the case.

Why does the compiler think there's a period here?

**Edit:**
I am using Wind River g++ 4.3.3 to build. It looks like the issue might simply be that this compiler is too old to support `mutable const` applied to a self-referential member of a class. Defining `BOOST_CB_ENABLE_DEBUG` to be 0 seems to be a way around this issue.

Comment: Does commenting out that line change the error ?

Comment: Yes, in that case the error is just from anything trying to reference `m_next`...a much more mundane error.

Comment: Is this the only compiler error? I would expect that this error is reported by a confused compiler due to another error earlier on...

Comment: I expect the same. It is not the only error, although it is the first error to be listed. I'll dig through the others just in case the ordering is mixed up.